# Want to get single database value

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, resultset

I have a login form which if is success to login. I want to get a name of the logged, here see my code:

```
 try {
             if(jTextField1.getText().equals(""))
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pleass Input Username");
        }
        else if(jPasswordField1.getText().equals(""))
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Input Password");
        }
        else
        {
            rs = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MsEmployee WHERE EmployeeID='"+jTextField1.getText()+"' And Password='"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"'");
            if (rs.next())
            {
             help.IDemployee = jTextField1.getText(); 
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success! welcome "+ help.IDemployee);
             MainMenu mm = new MainMenu(true);
             mm.setVisible(true);
             this.dispose();
            }else
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username not found!!");
            }
        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
        }
```

So I want to display the `EmployeeName` from `MSEmployee` which it got from `EmployeeID`. 
I think something like this:

```
String qry;
qry = "Select EmployeeName From MsEmplyee WHERE EmployeeID = '" + jtextField1.gettext() + "'" ;
```

But when I compile, its just print the text above, not get the value. Can anyone help please?

Comment: did you forgot "rs = con.executeQuery(qry)"; ??

Comment: Have you tried to execute the query generated directly on the database with some SQL tool?
What is the structure of the MsEmployee table?
There is a typo in the second code snippet, you use `MsEmplyee` instead of `MsEmployee`

Comment: Agree with András Kerekes. Which is right to use - MsEmplyee / MsEmployee?

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection. Never ever ever put the gui components directly in your query. In your case you should use a PreparedStatement with "?" to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, please check which name, MsEmplyee/MsEmployee, is correct.

This is not related to your problem but I think there can be one (possible) improvement in your code.

Instead of using

```
if(jTextField1.getText().equals(""))
```

It is better to use trim() method before using equals() method. So if user enters a space in jTextField1, your check will be bypassed in this case. So better to use trim() method to remove all first and last space characters from the string.

```
if(jTextField1.getText().trim().equals(""))
```

Same can be done for password field.

Comment: Better use "".equals(jTextField1.getText()) because you could end up with NPE

Comment: If "".equals(jTextField1.getText()) is used, the purpose of using trim() is not achieved. If space character is used, it will still bypass the check added to for empty inputs. About NPE, no there will never be a NPE in **this** case. Because if nothing is typed in JTextField, it will return "" and not null. But in other cases, yes I agree to better use "".equals() :)

Comment: @YogeshRalebhat I would never rely on the assumption that `getText` won't return a `null` value.  Somewhere around Java 1.4 it changed so that it wouldn't (so it has history of doing so) and there is no guarantee that it won't in the future (but I hope it doesn't)

Comment: hello everyone ,thanks for the reply, oh yes and i got typo in the post , it must be MsEmployee no MsEmplyee, i will explain detail about my problem,  in my db MsEmployee , i have 3 table , that contains EmployeeID ,EmployeeName,Password , and for that login form , i use EmployeeID and Password , that i want is , if the user is correctly login , the other form will show up and that contains label that show you the name of the EmployeeName that login,so what must i do is that some thing like i say  before or anything else ? can someone explain  me more detail please  ? thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your suggestion seems important as we cannot rely on what "getText" method is returning at current point of time. It is always better to have such programming practice which is future proof. Thanks for this clarification. I tried to search what this method was returning prior to Java 1.4, but I could not find any satisfactory link. If you have any link showing "getText" returning null and can share with us, it will be helpful.

Comment: @YogeshRalebhat I don't recall it begin document, it just hit the problem and app when I went back to check it some time later it was no longer occurring

Answer (score 0):

You did not read the result set value.

```
// help.IDemployee = jTextField1.getText(); 
help.IDemployee = rs.getString(1);
```

The column index is from 1 for the first column. Not from 0

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This !

String EmployeeName = rs.getString("Column Label In Database (Like EmployeeName)");

System.out.println(EmployeeName);